# sed: cut a string within a pattern

Tags: sed

I have many XHTML files whose contents are like:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not accessBean.isUserLoggedIn}">
    <h:form>
        <p:panel style="margin-top:10px">
            <table style="margin:10px">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">#{i.m['Login']}</td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <h:inputText value="#{accessBean.login}" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">#{i.m['Password']}</td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <h:inputSecret value="#{accessBean.password}" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <p:commandButton ajax="false" value="#{i.m['Submit']}" action="#{accessBean.login}" />
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

I want to replace every occurrence of `#{i.m['any-string>']}` with `any-string`, i.e., cut the string within the pattern.

I have created the following `sed` command

```
sed -e "s/#{i.m\['\(.*\)']}/\1/g"
```

And to run it recursively within a directory I could execute

```
find . -iname '*.xhtml' -type f -exec sed -i -e "s/#{i.m\['\(.*\)']}/\1/g" {} \;
```

<strike>Here, the `any-string` can be any **human-readable HTML displayable character**, i.e, alphabet, numbers, other characters etc. That's why I have used regex `(.*)`.</strike>

But it seems to be not working perfectly.

Here are some tests I made using `echo`:

1. ```
   $ echo "<td align=\"center\">#{i.m['Login']}</td>" | sed -e "s/#{i.m\['\(.*\)']}/\1/g"
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   <td align="center">Login</td>
   ```

   OK
2. ```
   $ echo "<p:commandButton  ajax=\"false\" value=\"#{i.m['Submit']}\" action=\"#{accessBean.login}\" />" | sed -e "s/#{i.m\['\(.*\)']}/\1/g"
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   <p:commandButton  ajax="false" value="Submit" action="#{accessBean.login}" />
   ```

   OK
3. ```
   $ echo "<p:commandButton ajax=\"false\" value=\"#{i.m['Submit']}\" action=\"#{accessBean.login}\" /> <td align=\"center\">#{i.m['Login']}</td>" | sed -e "s/#{i.m\['\(.*\)']}/\1/g"
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   <p:commandButton ajax="false" value="Submit']}" action="#{accessBean.login}" /> <td align="center">#{i.m['Login</td>
   ```

   NOK

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858)

Comment: Choose the right tool first. I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.).

Comment: @Cyrus, thanks for your response. I just updated the question and strikethroughed a part of it.

Comment: Though you should definitely use a proper XML parser like `xmlstartlet`, for your example, to replace the text leaving `LOGIN`, `PASSWORD` and `Submit` you could use the following regex: `sed "s/[#][{]i[.]m[[][']\([^']*\)['][]][}]/\1/" <file`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, could you please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it? Your solution worked like a charm. Also, it would be great if you could explain the expression a bit. Thanks :-)

Comment: @TapasBose Sure, will be glad to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your request, and as noted in my comment and the comment of others, you should definitely use a proper XML parser like `xmlstartlet` for proper XHTML parsing. A simple regex has no validation for what is left behind.

That being said, for your example (only), to replace the text leaving `LOGIN`, `PASSWORD` and `Submit` you could use the following regex:

```
sed "s/[#][{]i[.]m[[][']\([^']*\)['][]][}]/\1/" <file
```

Whenever you have to match characters that can also be part of the regex itself, it helps to explicitly make sure the character you want to match is treated as a character and not part of the regex expression. To do that you make use of a *character-class* (e.g. `[...]` where the characters between the brackets are matched. (if the first character in the character class is `'^'` it will invert the match -- i.e. match everything but what is in the class)

With that explanation, the regex should become clear. The regex uses the basic substitution form:

```
sed "s/find/replace/" file
```

**The 'find' REGEX**

- `[#]` - match the pound sign
- `[{]` - match the opening brace
- `i` - match the `'i'`
- `[.]` - explicitly match the `'.'` character (instead of `.` any character)
- `m` - match the `'m'`
- `[[]` - match the opening bracket
- `[']` - match the single quote
- `\(` - begin your capture group to capture text to reinsert as a *back reference*
- `[^']*` - match *zero-or-more* characters that are not a single-quote
- `\)` - end your capture group
- `[']` - match the single-quote as the next character
- `[]]` - match the closing bracket
- `[}]` - match the closing brace.

**The 'replace' REGEX**

All characters captured as part of the find capture group (between the `\(....\)`), are available to use as a back reference in the `replace` portion of the substitution. You can have more than one capture group in the `find` portion, which you reference in the replace part of the substitution as `\1, \2, ...` and so on. Here you have only a single capture group in the find portion, so whatever was matched can be used as the entire replacement, e.g.

- `\1` - to replace the whole mess with just the text that was captured with `[^']*`

**Example Use/Output**

For use with your example, it will properly leave `Login`, `Password` and `Submit` as indicated in your question, e.g.

```
sed "s/[#][{]i[.]m[[][']\([^']*\)['][]][}]/\1/" file
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not accessBean.isUserLoggedIn}">
    <h:form>
        <p:panel style="margin-top:10px">
            <table style="margin:10px">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">Login</td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <h:inputText value="#{accessBean.login}" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">Password</td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <h:inputSecret value="#{accessBean.password}" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <p:commandButton ajax="false" value="Submit" action="#{accessBean.login}" />
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Again, as a disclaimer and just good common sense, don't parse X/HTML with a regex, use a proper tool like `xmlstartlet`. Don't parse JSON with a regex, use a proper tools for the job like `jq` -- you get the drift. (but for this limited example, the regex works well, but it is fragile, if anything in the input changes, it will break -- which is why we have tools like `xmlstartlet` and `jq`)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you do not take the greedy nature of regexps into account. You need to prevent your regexp from gobbling up extra `'`s:

sed -e "s/#{i.m['([^']*)']}/\1/g"

This is also the reason why David C. Rankin's solution works. His regexp is unnecessarily complex, however.